# Error with Twit config in node.js

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

I'm brand new to all this so apologies if this isn't the right place to post, but I'm working on a NodeJS app using Twit.

This is what I have in the beginning where I declare my variables:

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var twitter = new Twit({
consumer_key:'XXX',
consumer_secret:'XXX',
access_token:'XXX',
access_token_secret:'XXX'
});
```

when I try to run it, I get this message:

"Error: Twit config must include consumer_key when using user auth."

I have doubled checked my keys, they are all correct. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting the same error all of a sudden, despite having deployed my bot for a couple of months already. Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error when picking up work on a directory I had not touched in some time. I looked around and realized I had to use

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to remind the node app where the environmental variables were stored.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dotenv library.

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

Your first line should be as below and you are good to go.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

More documentation and options are listed on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('the bot is starting!');
var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);
```

Use the code above to make it work. The config file that is made has the `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`, `access_token`, `access_token_secret` in a `module.exports` object.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same error until I found @Serrato's answer about using:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

However, since I was using a .env file to export my keys, what ended up working for me was to input into the terminal:

```
source .env
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to create an app on twitter in order to retrieve

consumer_key:'XXX',
consumer_secret:'XXX',
access_token:'XXX',
access_token_secret:'XXX'

Go to https://apps.twitter.com/app/new and copy these keys from there and paste them back in your code